# Updating an old answer broke all of the links

Tags: bug, external-links

In the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273378/262056), someone pointed out that one of the old blog post links was dead.  I updated the answer to clarify the problem and remove the dead link, but now many of the markdown links are no longer getting parsed into an actual link.

I tried renumbering the footnotes, and I tried reverting the change, to no avail.

Comment: One solution would be to delete the whole question since it's off-topic ;)

Comment: One more delete vote needed and the problem goes awaaaaaayyyyyyyyy

Comment: Understandable, but the buggy link behavior is still a concern.

Comment: Also, maybe it should be relocated to maybe programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Will: Wrong, four more votes...

Comment: @deduplicator Wait, was it upvoted?  Oh, damnit.  45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes) has to say:

> Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:
>
> 1. They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
> 2. The begin and end tags of the outermost block element must not be indented.
> 3. Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.
>
> ```
> <pre>
>     You can <em>not</em> use Markdown in here.
> </pre>
> ```

Point 3 is what's most important here. It's much easier to use Markdown all the way than trying to mix it with HTML. You have a lot of `[…][…]` style links inside `<p>` and `<blockquote>` elements. You need to change the links to proper `<a>` elements, or (perhaps preferably), replace your HTML with their Markdown equivalents:

- Blank lines between paragraphs.
- `>`  prefix instead of `<blockquote>···</blockquote>`
- `**···**` or `__···__` instead of `<strong>···</strong>`

If you need more than one block level element inside a list item, you need to prefix the subsequent blocks with four spaces to continue the list item. Without this prefix, the next block will start a new list item.

It is possible that the rendering rules have changed since you last updated your post. The rendered HTML is stored together with the Markdown and is not re-rendered until the post is edited.

Comment: Okay, so I guess the markdown parser changed?  This is an old answer, and the current content of the body produced correct links.

Comment: I reformatted with proper markdown, and that fixed it.